# How do I number my data sequentially while skipping the blanks and then beginning with a new subset of numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Below is a sample spreadsheet.  My data is in column A (below is only a sample...there may be 100 items in the first grouping followed by 2 blanks, and then 50 items in the next grouping)...In column B, I need to sequentially number each grouping of items starting with a new 1000 number.

Desired output:

```
 A            B
Apples      1000

Bananas     1001

Peaches     1002

Blank row

Blank row

Grapes      2000

Pears       2001

Blank row

Blank row

Kiwi        3000

Avocado     3001

Pineapple   3002
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `=IF(F2="","",IF(MAX($G$1:G1)=0,1000,IF(AND(F2<>"",G1<>""),G1+1,IF(AND(F2<>"",G1=""),FLOOR(MAX($G$1:G1)+1000,1000),""))))`

This assumes your labels are in column F and your IDs in column G.

Here is what is going on in more detail:

```
=IF(F2="","",                        --If label is blank leave ID blank
  IF(MAX($G$1:G1)=0,1000,            --If no ID rows above then start at 1000
   IF(AND(F2<>"",G1<>""),G1+1,       --If Id row directly above then increment by 1
    IF(AND(F2<>"",G1=""),FLOOR(MAX($G$1:G1)+1000,1000) 
                                     --If new block add 1000 and round to nearest 1000
    ,""                              --Otherwise leave blank
   ))))
```

And here's your output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In B1, simply type in 1000 as you know this value exists. The rest, we can use a worksheet formula!

Then in B2 add this formula

```
=IF(AND(A1<>"",A2<>""),B1+1,IF(AND(A1="",A2<>""),ROUNDUP(MAX($B$1:$B1 )+ 1,-3),""))
```

Drag it down!
[image]